# How should I deal with the following suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

While doing the [Suggested Edit reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review), I stumbled upon this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/35098717).
The answer seems to be accepted, and there are 698 people finding that answer useful, but still somebody seems to be modifying that answer completely.

Can somebody (like a moderator) check what's going on here?

Answer (score 9):

It's a 1-rep user completely re-writing an well-established answer, completely changing what it says...

That's a straightforward "Conflicts with author's intent" rejection.

Comment: Can this be avoided?

Comment: Avoid what? That a 1-rep user performs such an edit?

Comment: @BDL does the "Protect" option for questions take away edit proposals from 1-rep users, or only the option to add a new answer?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: The question was and is protected since 2016, since it was possible to edit, I guess protection doesn't prevent edits.

Comment: Protection only blocks answers from low rep users, nothing more.

Comment: Locks can prevent edits entirely, but they also prevent, among other things, _votes_, so they are pretty much never used long-term to prevent incorrect edits to answers, with [very rare exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/208273).

Comment: @Dominique You can't avoid uncontrolled enthusiasm. Hence: review queues as a damage prevention tool, the rollback feature as a cleanup tool should the damage prevention tool fail us and meta as an educational tool. All three tools are far from perfect unfortunately, but it's what we got.